Remote control and display of embedded Linux devices
Background information - We have two custom embedded Linux devices that both contain their own GUI for operating and controlling each device and it's software/firmware. The devices are class 2 medical devices and do not have any internet connection. Both of these embedded Linux devices are custom SoC PCB's that contain an AM3354 ARM Cortex-A8, SDRAM, Flash, USB, I2C, LCD Touch panel, SSH, etc. Both devices contain a custom GUI application that were created using Qt 5.7.1 minGW 32bit, using C++ and QtQuickCompiler. The Linux architecture of each device system is the exact same.
What we are trying to accomplish, is to have the ability to remote display from one device to the other, while also having the ability to control the operation and functions of the GUI of the targeted device. This behavior is similar to having remote access from one desktop to another desktop. Below are key objectives we want to accomplish.

Remote connection from one device to the other
When remote connection is established from one device to the other, have the ability to control and operate the targeted device's software from the remote device's software
Mirror the display from the targeted device to the remote device

Our questions are: Do our Linux devices have the ability to do this? Any recommendations on what sort of implementation is used for something like this?
I've done a ton of research and I know that this is not anything new in the realm of embedded devices, but this is our first time trying to achieve something like this. If there is any other additional information that needs to be provided, please let me know!

I would say this looks like a VNC setup. I have such configuration at work to help users already logged on a computer. We can take the control of the machine via x11VNC and move cursor and type to show the user what to do. But this is on standard linux installations. On your side, you'll have to compile/install that using your tools.

@Dheitkamp96 : I am following your Q. Please post if you find that the above recommendation will "fit" in your system. Thanks

@darxmurf Thank you for the response.  We will do our due diligence and research this to see if it can be applied our devices. I will follow up once I have more feedback.

@shellter Sounds good, will do.

If you use VNC do so through a secure tunnel like SSH or TLS.  If you need management there are commercial options that are more advanced in terms of managing their own credentials and having central appliances.

@davolfman you are right but it looks like those 2 machines are only connected together without any other network access. In this case securing the tunnel won't add anything

@davolfman Both of these devices have a local IP that can be connected via serial connection. But you are correct that they are not connected to a network such as WAN. Am I correct to assume that if they are connected together via serial connection, that they would be communicating on their local network? Similar to LAN.

Serial is not great for doing GUIs.  You might need to use PPP or similar to turn that into a network interface before you can use something like VNC or NX or X transparency.  Also serial tends to limit you to UART speeds topping out at something like 115.2 kbps or 230.4 kbps.  This puts you in the lower tiers of performance for GUI remote control.  Ethernet is strictly better.

Or maybe set up tmux or screen so you can "talk" to cmd-lines between machines. Also maybe you can find an ncurses based app that won't require the higher bandwidth required by GUIs.
